# Magento 2: Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am cloning hellyhansen site. In that i need to do the checkout page.

[image]

Hellyhansen checkout page

[image]

My local magento. Based on the hellyhansen site, I need to clone the page.

Kindly help and suggest.

Comment: It looks like that site is just using an extension for their checkout. Some like: https://www.magestore.com/magento-one-step-checkout-extension.html